# Adjusting the Play Button Size for the Kaltura Video Player?

Tags: php, html5-video, embedding, kaltura

I'm having trouble adjusting the size of the play button on an embedded Kultura video. When I embed a video within a smaller container or screen size, the play button is so large that it nearly covers the entire thumbnail on any state. (see attachment) Does anyone know how I can adjust the button's size?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Player Skin Overrides](https://vpaas.kaltura.com/documentation/04_Web-Video-Player/Player-Customization.html#core-player-skin-external-css-overrides) and about [Player States](https://vpaas.kaltura.com/documentation/04_Web-Video-Player/Player-Customization.html#player-states-css).

Essentially, you would need to add custom CSS override, and include something like the below example;

```
.size-tiny .largePlayBtn {
  width: 8px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```